# FQL query to get all friends events in a given city

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I tried to limit to a latitude/longitude range but don't know how to do it
Here's what I've tried

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (
   SELECT eid FROM event_member 
   WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())  OR uid = me())
   )
AND start_time > now()
AND venue.latitude  < '-22.821757'
AND venue.latitude  > '-23.056989'
```

but the coordinate comparison doensn't work because i'm comparing to a string

If I take away the quotes I get:

```
(#601) Parser error: unexpected '-' at position 233
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Thanks

Comment: Docs show that lat and lng are floats, not strings. So why are you wrapping those in strings?

Comment: If I take away the quotes I get: (#601) Parser error: unexpected '-' at position 233